# Tkinter labels change window size even after resizable

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know if there is a way to make labels NOT change the window size. I've tried master.resizable(width=False, height=False) but it doesn't work. Same with adding buttons, the window size still changes. Also, I want it to work with `.grid` and not only `.pack`. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
master = tk.Tk()

lel = tk.Button()
lel["text"] = "ooo"
lel.pack(side = "top")
master.configure(width=500, height=500)
master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
mainloop()
```

Comment: From a usability point of view, makeing a window not resizeable isn't very user-friendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))
```

[image]